# How to filter based on One to many & Many to One relations table Spring JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a table Student which is one to many with Address table and Address have many to one relation to Student table.

```
public class Student{
  @Id
  @Column(name = "stud_id", nullable = false)
  private String stud_id;
  @Column(name = "stud_name", nullable = false)
  private String stud_name;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
  private List<Address> addresses;
}

public class Address{
  @Id
  @Column(name = "address_id", nullable = false)
  private String address_id;
  @Column(name = "address_name", nullable = false)
  private String address_name;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "stud_id", nullable = false)
  private Student student;
}
```

How do i filter something like get All Student addresses address_name in 'Something'.
Expected return should be Student object so that i can traverse into Address which is filtered as 'Something' using Spring JPA repository with SpringConvention or by @Query. Please help

Answer (score 1):

try this if you have a collection of addressNames to filter against

```
@Query("select a.student from Address a where a.address_name in (?1)")
List<Student> findStudentsByAddressNameIn(List<String> addressNames);
```

or if you want to filter by address_name = 'something'

```
@Query("select a.student from Address a where a.address_name = ?1")
List<Student> findStudentsByAddressName(String addressNameFilter);
```

or if you want to filter by address_name contains 'something' set addressNameFilter to "%" + addressNameFilter + "%" and use

```
@Query("select a.student from Address a where a.address_name like ?1")
List<Student> findStudentsByAddressNameLike(String addressNameFilter);
```

Comment: I think the above implementation gives student who matches specific address_name. But since the relation student@onetomany & address@manytoone, the student object will show other address the student added!! is that still expected?

Comment: @Satscreate oh i did not understand: do you only need student who have only one address with addressName equal to the addressNameFilter?

Comment: yes. So is that something which is not possible with one to many isn't? Or do I need to make different join?

Comment: @Satscreate could something like `@Query("select s from Address a join a.student as s where a.address_name like ?1 and size(s. addresses) = 1")` work?